# Do people use the phrase "in exhibition"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

> The Bosarges’ $5 million mummy now is **in exhibition** at the Museum of Natural History in Houston. ([source](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/06/how-marie-and-ed-bosarges-divorce-spotlights-south-dakotas-asset-trusts.html))

I am not familiar with "in exhibition". I would always use "on exhibition". My own research on Google Ngrams and Google Books is inconclusive, showing "in exhibition" being far less common. I am not sure "in exhibition" means exactly the same as "on exhibition".

Do people say "in exhibition"?

Comment: See this instead. Many false positives, but quite a few uses like those in the book.

Comment: The cited source no longer says "in exhibition". So either they changed it, or the OP misquoted it.

Comment: It's just poorly expressed. The writers often knock off these pieces at a very fast clip and don't have time to reread themselves, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

No, people do not generally say, "in exhibition".
Better alternatives are "on exhibit", or "in an exhibition"

I checked the source you provided, for more context. It reads as follows:

> They bought $1 million tapestries and a $5 million Egyptian mummy, now in a Houston museum.

Either of the two suggestions I made above would fit here.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40439/exhibition-or-exhibit) deals with differences between ***exhibit*** and ***exhibition***.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exhibition) definitely gives ***be on exhibit*** as a set phrase (and so do [other dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=to%20be%20on%20exhibition%20meaning&safe=strict&biw=1760&bih=811&sxsrf=ALeKk02qv6CQeVYOc77rFmlklIuvUYHO0Q%3A1625225504915&ei=IPneYOejN9qAhbIPnPWhiA8&oq=be%20on%20exhibition&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQBRAeOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAcQChAeOggIABAIEAcQHjoECAAQDToICAAQDRAFEB5KBAhBGABQ378EWNPFBGCr0wRoAXACeACAAfcBiAGKBJIBBTIuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) too):

> if something is ***on exhibition***, it is in a place where the public can come to look at it:
>
> - All the latest cars are ***on exhibition*** at the Motor Show.

Strangely enough, if you insert the indefinite article ***an***, [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20exhibition%2C%20on%20exhibition%2C%20in%20an%20exhibition%2C%20on%20an%20exhibition&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20exhibition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20exhibition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20an%20exhibition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20an%20exhibition%3B%2Cc0) shows that ***[in an exhibition](https://textranch.com/217625/in-an-exhibition/or/on-an-exhibition/)*** is more common than ***on an exhibition***. It is not excluded that the author of that article might have confused the two. A [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20exhibition%22&safe=strict&biw=1760&bih=849&sxsrf=ALeKk00oJaPMkNCPz0CoLSlkd86L-s1Q3g%3A1625225098875&ei=ivfeYI7zNIfGgQbl6o2YDg&oq=%22in%20exhibition%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB46BwgjELADECc6BwgAEEcQsAM6AggAOgYIABAWEB46CAgAEBYQChAeSgQIQRgAUNVfWPp4YImCAWgBcAJ4AIAB7gKIAagFkgEHMi4xLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiO4Mqlo8TxAhUHY8AKHWV1A-M4ChDh1QMIDQ&uact=5) of the expression "in exhibition" finds quite a few instances, but not in the way "on exhibition" is used:

> - world champion boxers ***in exhibition fights***
> - Interested ***in Exhibition*** London?
> - Women ***in Exhibition***™ is a global cinema network, created to empower women ***in the exhibition industry***.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible they were thinking of *On Exhibition* when they were saying *In an exhibition*. The result: *In Exhibition* would be not an unusual mistake, to make what you are saying fit what you think it is supposed to look like. It is likely why there is **any** occurrence of the other phrase.